# how to get _id from json decode

Tags: php, json, mongodb

Here is my json which I get from mongodb:

```
object(stdClass)[6]
  public '572453d55addfab49090ea71' => 
    object(stdClass)[7]
      public '_id' => 
        object(stdClass)[8]
          public '$id' => string '572453d55addfab49090ea71' (length=24)
      public 'location' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => float 24.8615
          1 => float 67.0099
```

In order to access location I have to use following statement in php

```
$lat= $j->{'572453d55addfab49090ea71'}->location[0];
```

I want to make it generic by first getting _id and then using the above statement. I have tried following statements which all return error:

```
 echo $arr= json_encode(iterator_to_array($cursor));
     echo var_dump(json_decode($arr));
$j = json_decode($arr,false);
     $lat = $j->_id->id;
    $lng = $j->id->location[1];
```

Kindly tell me how to solve this issue

Comment: can you show your json format?

Comment: @Irfan {"572453d55addfab49090ea71":{"_id":{"$id":"572453d55addfab49090ea71"},"location":[24.8615,67.0099]}}

Comment: what is the output of `echo var_dump(json_decode($arr));`?

Comment: Try to access `id` as `$j->{'_id'}->{'$id'};`

Comment: @Alex doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another parameter `true` with `json_decode()`, then you will get the result as php array format.

use the code below to print array and paste the result here, then i'll let you know how you can print your _id

```
$jsonDecode = json_decode($yourJson, true);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($jsonDecode);
```

Resulted array should be like this

```
 Array ( 
        [572453d55addfab49090ea71] =>
                 Array ( 
                        [_id] => 
                                Array ( 
                                        [$id] => 572453d55addfab49090ea71 
                                      )

                         [location] => Array ( [0] => 24.8615 [1] => 67.0099 ) 
                       ) 
        )
```

Finally use:

```
$_id = array_column($jsonDecode, '_id');
echo $_id[0]['$id'];
```

Comment: One line code can be done in comment. you can see above. No offence

Comment: It's okay, I'll take care of this thing next time.. ThankYou

Comment: Actually why i am saying this because you may face some -ve mark, lot of time i saw this.

Comment: @Anant, but i had to add bit explanation about `json_decode()` and further one line is written so thats why, I put this in answer..

Comment: Here it is :  Array
(
    [572453d55addfab49090ea71] => Array
        (
            [_id] => Array
                (
                    [$id] => 572453d55addfab49090ea71
                )

            [location] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 24.8615
                    [1] => 67.0099
                )

        )

)

Comment: @ManjeetBarnala This is what Im trying to avoid. I dont want to enter 572453d55addfab49090ea71 explicitly. It should be generic because if  I get some other record from database next time then this would give an error

Comment: @puffles, I've edited the answer, [ARRAY COLUMN](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) will work for you :)